# Echoing html link mailto

Tags: cakephp, ckeditor, cakephp-2.1

I'm using Ckeditor on a field of a CakePHP form.

No problems saving the information on the database the problem is when I echo the content of that field. If the field as a link of the type mailto I get a *denied:* in the beginning of the href attribute.

For example:

```
<a href="denied:mailto:name@domain.com">name@domain.com</a>
```

To echo the field value I'm using:

```
echo $data['Ent']['text'];
```

Comment: Are you sure your HTML markup is correct? This looks as some other attribute leaked a little bit and the browser tried to put things back together. Also did you `var_dump`-ed `$data['Ent']['text']`?

Comment: You are correct I forget I was using htmLawed on this field. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

you can use :

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link($v['mail'],'mailto:'.$v['mail'],array('target' => '_blank'));?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Dont know why Ckediter is doing that but you can remove it using jquery

```
<a id="link1" href="denied:mailto:name@domain.com">name@domain.com</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
  $("#link1").attr("href","mailto:name@domain.com");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Probably I didn't explain correctly. The problem is not in ckeditor because the information is correct in the database. The problem should be on CakepPHP